# O_DIRECT in ext4 with data=journaled mount option enabled

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, ext4

As far as I know in ext4 the O_DIRECT flag support with journalling on was added only in some recent kernel versions. I know it wasn't there with 3.0.0 kernel but it already works fine with 3.4, so I'm trying to find out which is the lowest possible version, not to disable the feature everywhere but to do it after a kernel version check. I looked up some ext4 documentations, found some patches but still don't know the exact version. Is there any help you can suggest?

Comment: Have you seen [this commit](http://git.kernel.org/?p=linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git;a=commit;h=84ebd795613488992b273220c2937d575d27d2a9)? It seems, ext4 may just look like it has support for O_DIRECT with journaling.

Comment: By the way, it is for Spruce project, I suppose, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it is. And yes, I know it's not really a support, but at least system calls don't fail in new kernels. It doesn't matter now anyway, we now let them fail and just mark as known issue. Thanks for the response :)